# How can I refresh the cookie to reflect a user changing their email?

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, simplemembership

I'm using WebSecurity and SimpleMembershipProvider to log users in.

The user can change their email

```vb
Dim memberId As Integer = 1

Dim context As UsersContext = New UsersContext
Dim userProfile As UserProfile =
    context.UserProfiles.Where(Function(f) f.UserId = memberId).SingleOrDefault()
' Email before the change: "a@a.com"
userProfile.UserName = "b@b.com"
context.SaveChanges()
```

After this updates, however, the HttpContext still reports the user as their old email.

```vb
' Name is "a@a.com" but should be "b@b.com"
HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
```

At first I thought I could just log the user out and back in

```vb
WebSecurity.Logout()
' but I don't have the user's password
WebSecurity.Login("b@b.com", "???")
```

How can I refresh the authentication cookie somehow to reflect a user changing their login details?

Comment: log user out and log em back in with new username

Comment: But I'm using `WebSecurity` and the `Login` method needs to be passed a username and password. Any ideas?

Comment: yick. if you can't do it without password, its gona get messy... will think on it...

Comment: Me too :P I'm thinking the only way is to either make my own custom MembershipProvider or manipulate cookies directly.

Comment: manipulating cookies is ugly. are you by any chance using oauth with websecurity?

Comment: It so is :( I'm not using OAuth.

Comment: longshot... can you request password during email change (under context of confirming user identity -- added security)

Comment: Definitely something I thought of too and something that I will consider. It wouldn't be a bad idea to ask them for password confirmation for changing something so vital (it is their login after all).

Comment: I'd say requesting password is a reasonable answer. If you put it up I'll +1 it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change a cookie through membership, you seem stuck with logging the user out and logging them back in.

The dilemma you are faced with at that point is ***how to log a user in without their passowrd***.

The best prospect seems to be asking for the user's password during username change. This has a reasonable feel to it and arms you with the password.

Comment: While my solution works, I think I'll recommend this one for anyone looking for an answer to the problem. If you're going to allow users to change their login details (i.e. username/email) then requiring a password input at the same time is a good security measure. You can then use their inputted username and password to log them out and then back in.

Answer (score 1):

OP here. This is one (ugly?) way to do it:

```vb
Dim newEmail As String = "b@b.com"

Dim ticket As FormsAuthenticationTicket =
    New FormsAuthenticationTicket(newEmail, False, FormsAuthentication.Timeout.Minutes)

Dim identity As IIdentity = New FormsIdentity(ticket)

HttpContext.Current.User = New RolePrincipal(identity)

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(newEmail, False)
```

It works fine, but it seems a bit ugly. It's forcing my app to become dependent on `FormsAuthentication` (correct?)

@Dave A

Do you think I should use this code but put it into my own custom `MemershipProvider` (is that right? Is it the `MembershipProvider` that handles this?)

Comment: It's not that ugly. But I agree that it doesn't seem DRY. I'd think of it as a good first step. You could create your own provider to make this simpler, but that seems like out of proportion investment to avoid this.